# When am I allowed to let $n \rightarrow \infty$ in measure theory proofs?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory

I’m somehow confused by this simple thing, let me elaborate on the question by means of an example, in the following it is proved that for a function that obeys monotonicity and $\sigma$-subadditivity $\mu: \Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, on a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ and $(A_k)_k, A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$, $\forall k \ A_k \in \Sigma$, the following holds:

$$
\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^m\mu(A_k) \Rightarrow \mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^ {\infty} A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)
$$

This is done by considering monotonicity: $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k)  \geq \mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k)= \sum_{k=1}^m\mu(A_k)$ and **then** letting $m \rightarrow \infty$ and considering $\sigma$-subadditivity for the lower bound: $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k) \geq \mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) $.

Why weren‘t we able to let $m \rightarrow \infty$ directly, i.e. why is it allowed to do that with the sum but not with the union? I‘ve seen this a cupped of times now and it seems random when they are allowed to do it and when they don’t. I‘d be greatfull for any help:)

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to argue that $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \mu(\cup_{k=1}^m A_k) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \mu(A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k)$. But how do you know that $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \mu(\cup_{k=1}^m A_k)$?

Comment: Exactly! I want to know when I am allowed to do exactly that:)

Comment: But, if you want to assert that $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \mu(\cup_{k=1}^m A_k)$, the burden of proof is on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property which you are talking about is known as the sub-$\sigma$-aditivity. In order to prove it, consider the sequence of events $B_{1} = \varnothing$ and $B_{n} = A_{n}\backslash\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_{k}$ for $n\geq 2$. Then one has the desired result:
\begin{align*}
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k\geq 1}A_{n}\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_{n}\right) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\mu(B_{n}) \leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\mu(A_{n})
\end{align*}
just as desired, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, let $(A_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of events in the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra. Suppose as well that $A_{n}\subseteq A_{n+1}$ and $A = \bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_{n}$ for $n\geq 1$, where $A_{0} = \varnothing$. Then, if we consider the auxiliary sequence $B_{n} = A_{n}\backslash A_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$, one gets the desired claim:
\begin{align*}
\mu(A) & = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_{n}\right)\\\\
& = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_{n}\right)\\\\
& = \sum_{n\geq 1}\mu(B_{n})\\\\
& = \sum_{n\geq 1}\mu(A_{n}\backslash A_{n-1})\\\\
& = \sum_{n\geq 1}(\mu(A_{n}) - \mu(A_{n-1}))\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\mu(A_{k}) - \mu(A_{k-1}))\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_{n})
\end{align*}

and we are done!

Comment: Thank you:) I think you just proved that $\sigma$-additivity implies $\sigma$-subadditivity, right? But I don‘t have an issue with that in itself but only specifically with turning finite sums/unions into infinite ones, when am I allowed to do that? My proof was just meant as an example that contained this step:)

Comment: @HenryT. That's right! I have also edited my answer to provide restrictions which allow us to exchange limits.

Comment: Let $S=\mu (\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n)$ and let $S_n=\mu (\cup_{1\le k\le n}A_k) .$ We don't know, a priori, whether $S=\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n,$ so if we  just let $n\to\infty$ in the expression for $S_n$ then we dk what we have. But we have $S\ge S_n$ for every $n,$ so $S\ge \sup_n S_n=\lim_n S_n=\sum_n\mu (A_n).$ In a separate step we use countable sub-additivity to obtain $S\le \sum_n\mu (A_n).$